# Setting and retrieving custom object in $routeParams in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When performing a redirect to another partial view in AngularJS using

$location.path('/view2')

Is it possible to set a custom object in $routeParams and then retrieve that in the controller for view2?

The examples I see show how to do this by passing an ID in the url - $location.path('/view2/ID') and then retrieve the ID using $routeParams.ID but how can I pass any javascript object?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Services](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) ,they allow you to pass object from view to other.

Comment: This won't allow the user to keep the data after reloading the view though

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the `$location` service represent a change to the browser address bar so they are string based.

So basically there are 2 options:

- You convert your object to an url compatible string and pass it in the url
- You store your object in a data container (e.g. scope or rootScope), change your location and then fetch the data again from the data container.

The second option is definitely more reliable but technically the first option is valid so it's worth mentioning.

Hope that helps!